# Ajax reloads page instead of submitting the request

Tags: javascript, ajax, ajaxform

I have an Ajax script that causes the entire page to reload without ever submitting the URL for the request in the script. The server logs show the page URL as being re-submitted. Adding an alert demonstrates that the function is being run, but the embedded URL seems to be ignored. When used by itself, the request URL in the script returns the correct data.

Why isn't the embedded URL applied?

Another Ajax script on the same page works fine using a var named *xhttp* instead of *xfiles* so there's no conflict in that.

```
 function rlist() {
        var xfiles = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xfiles.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("filelist").innerHTML =
                this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xfiles.open("GET", "/cgi-bin/cnc.cgi?precert~patients~rlist~813527153~0975184859230735~~6306919737~622156596S", true);
        xfiles.send();
    }
```

The objective is to refresh a small table of uploaded files. The responseText contains the table html with links. That can't be the issue here though since the URL is never submitted in the first place.

Comment: How are you triggering this function?

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="rlist();">Refresh List</a>

Answer (score 0):

Swetank Poddar actually had the right idea... As it turns out, it was user error. I had left out the colon in javascript:void(0) and continuously overlooked it. So the Ajax was running correctly but the typo in the link was causing the page to subsequently reload. It was all so fast that it wasn't obvious and the database on the server showed the last processed hit as the link to load the page in the first place, which was the link to reload it as well.